# Is it possible to subset a pandas dataframe based on several combinations of conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, subset

I am trying to subset a **pandas dataframe** based on **several conditions**. I have attempted something like this:

```
subset_df = df[((df['language'] != 'es') and (df['language'] == 'eu')) | ((df['language'] == 'es') and (df['lang_conf'] < 1))]
```

But I get this error:

`The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Any ideas of how I could make this work or some different solution to achieve subsetting based on several nested conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace and by &, like this:

```
subset_df = df[((df['language'] != 'es') & (df['language'] == 'eu')) | ((df['language'] == 'es') & (df['lang_conf'] < 1))]
```